# Angular, why my button doesn't trigger anything?

Tags: angular, typescript, button, dom-events, mouseevent

So, I'm trying to do a form to get some data (the name and email), but before trying to wire it to my database I would like to test that it does at least recognize what I'm doing, here is the catch:
It seems like my button isn't triggering anything, I've even tried to do a simplest button to test if I had an easy to see mistake yet it doesn't work neither.

Typescript of the page:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserServiceService } from '../user-service.service';
import { User } from '../user';

import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-form',
  templateUrl: './user-form.component.html',
  styleUrl: './user-form.component.scss'
})
export class UserFormComponent implements OnInit{
    Name= new FormControl('');
    email= new FormControl('');
 

  user : User;

  constructor (private userService: UserServiceService){
    this.user = new User();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("starting things");
  }

  DoSubmit(){
    console.log("submitting...");
    let name = this.Name.value;
    let mail = this.email.value;
    let message = "Data is:" + name + " " + mail;
    this.userService.save(this.user).subscribe();
    console.log("Submitted");
    console.log(message)
    this.Name= new FormControl('');
    this.email= new FormControl('');
  }

  DoTest(){
    console.log("I did get trigger");
  }
}
```

The HTML of the page:

```
<form (onSubmit)="DoSubmit()">

    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input id="name" type="text" formControlName="tName" value="Erwan">
  
    <br>
    <label for="last-name">email: </label>
    <input id="last-name" class="form-control" type="mail" formControlName="email" value="emaignemontamat@hn-services.fr" size=60 >

    <button class="form-control" type="button" class="btn" (click)="DoSubmit()">Submit</button>
  
  </form>

  
  <button (click)="DoTest()">Save</button>
```

Between each "starting things" I've tried several time to push that button
[image]

Thanks for your time and your guidance I'm aware it may be a silly mistake but I don't know where it comes from

I did try to verify that I didn't forgot the "()" as it was mentionned in a few posts, I did try a simplest button according to the [event binding exemple from angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding)

I was at the very least expecting a log of "I did get trigger" when using the second button

Answer (score 1):

Please change the button to inside the form, this will ensure the button will trigger the `ngSubmit` then you need to change the button type to `submit` this will call the method! Finally in the form instead of `onSubmit` you can change it to `ngSubmit`.

Another improvement is that you can wrap the form controls inside a form group, this will ensure the form as a whole is valid. Also you can access all the values just by doing `this.formGroup.value`!

Final changes

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import 'zone.js';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="DoSubmit()">
      <label for="name">Name: </label>
      <input id="name" type="text" formControlName="Name">
      <br>
      <label for="last-name">email: </label>
      <input id="last-name" class="form-control" type="mail" formControlName="email" size=60 >
      <button class="form-control" type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class App {
  formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    Name: new FormControl('Erwan'),
    email: new FormControl('emaignemontamat@hn-services.fr'),
  });

  // user : User;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    // this.user = new User();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('starting things');
  }

  DoSubmit() {
    console.log('submitting...');
    let values = this.formGroup.value;
    let message = 'Data is:' + values.Name + ' ' + values.email;
    alert(message);
    this.userService.save(values).subscribe();
    console.log('Submitted');
    console.log(message);
    this.formGroup.patchValue({
      Name: '',
      email: '',
    });
  }

  DoTest() {
    console.log('I did get trigger');
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ofzfvw)

[Official Docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Comment: Seems like it does something (redirecting me to the homepage) however it doesn't trigger the DoSubmit (not sending anything in the console log even if it should), I've literally copy pasted your answer to try

Comment: @ErwanMaigneMontamat updated my answer with a working example for your reference!